# PHP output buffering Loop and Jquery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, comet, infinite-loop

I was reading a lot of things about comet programming but I'm thinking if this implementation could be possible.

this is my jscript

```
$.ajax({
   url:"mypage.php",
   onProgress:{function(rsp){ //i know there is no such function like this
     $("#mydiv").append(rsp+"<br>");
   }}
});
```

and this is my mypage.php

```
<?php
    while(true){
    ob_start();
      echo time();
    ob_flush();
    }
    ?>
```

now what i want is my ajax request would fetch results during progress. Is this possible?

Comment: Petah's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740646/jquery-ajax-read-the-stream-incrementally This solution works a treat for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this thing to happen you have to use comet technique....
please refer

[What is the best way of showing progress on an Ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901495/what-is-the-best-way-of-showing-progress-on-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1):

Heres the polling way todo it, if your only looking to grab the time. why have an infinite loop using resources.

```
<?php
//polling.php
if(isset($_GET['poll']) && $_GET['poll']=='1'){
$out = array('thetime'=>date("F j, Y, g:i:s a")); 
echo json_encode($out);
die;
}
?>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function poll(){
   setTimeout(function(){

      $.ajax({ url: "http://localhost/polling.php?poll=1",cache: false,
      success: function(data){
      //Do something with returned json
      $("#time").replaceWith("<p id=\"time\">The Server Time & Date is: "+ data.thetime +"</p>");
        //Next poll
        poll();
      }, dataType: "json"});
     // 1/2 a sec
  }, 500);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    poll();
});
</script>

<p id="time">The Server Time & Date is: <?php echo date("F j, Y, g:i:s a");?></p>
```