# Response.Flush With Ajax is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, comet, asp.net-4.5

I am following the following sample to create a very simple Comet in ASP.NET 4.5. [What is the best way of showing progress on an Ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901495/what-is-the-best-way-of-showing-progress-on-an-ajax-call)

I have also downloaded the sample from http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2007/07/08/creating-comet-applications-with-aspnet/. I am not getting any response from Server.

Is Response.Flush is changed in ASp.NEt 4.5?

**Update:** Just remove the Thread.Sleep, everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

I think dose not have radical change just [add](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet/whats-new#_Toc318097375) Asynchronously flushing a response

Asynchronously flushing a response

> Sending responses to an HTTP client can take considerable time when
>   the client is far away or has a low-bandwidth connection. Normally
>   ASP.NET buffers the response bytes as they are created by an
>   application. ASP.NET then performs a single send operation of the
>   accrued buffers at the very end of request processing.
>
> > If the buffered response is large (for example, streaming a large file
> >     to a client), you must periodically call HttpResponse.Flush to send
> >     buffered output to the client and keep memory usage under control.
> >     However, because Flush is a synchronous call, iteratively calling
> >     Flush still consumes a thread for the duration of potentially
> >     long-running requests.
> >
> > ASP.NET 4.5 adds support for performing flushes asynchronously using
> >     the BeginFlush and EndFlush methods of the HttpResponse class. Using
> >     these methods, you can create asynchronous modules and asynchronous
> >     handlers that incrementally send data to a client without tying up
> >     operating-system threads. In between BeginFlush and EndFlush calls,
> >     ASP.NET releases the current thread. This substantially reduces the
> >     total number of active threads that are needed in order to support
> >     long-running HTTP downloads.

Comment: I am aware of this man. I am asking why Response.Flush is not working?