# CSV import over Ajax fails when over 2000 requests, causing server failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajax-request

I'm trying to import CSV data to MySQL over Ajax for an email program. Everything works good for 2000 Ajax requests but then the browser/server gives failures.

I tried several approaches, but I can't find a solution.

My code:

```
<?php
$zeilen = file('uploads/'.$dateipfad);

$gesamtzeilen = count($zeilen);

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
datenzeilen = []; <? php foreach($zeilen as $zeile) { ?>
        datenzeilen.push( <? php echo json_encode($zeile); ?> ); <? php
} ?>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
for (var i = 0; i < datenzeilen.length; i++) {
    var aktuelledaten = datenzeilen[i];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "import.php",
        data: {
            trennzeichen: <? php echo '"'.$trennzeichen.
            '"'; ?> ,
            empfaengerliste: <? php echo '"'.$empfaengerliste.
            '"'; ?> ,
            aktuelle_daten: aktuelledaten,
            csvfelder: <? php echo '"'.implode(",", $csv_names).
            '"'; ?>
        },
        success: function (strResponse) {
            var gesamt = <? php echo $gesamtzeilen; ?> ;
            document.getElementById("gesamtanzahl").innerHTML = gesamt;
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: In other words, your script contains over 2000 lines such as `datenzeilen.push(...)`?

Comment: yes in my testfile there are 20.000 lines.

Comment: I suggest that you redesign your application altogether.  What you're doing is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Ok why this? I know my programming knowledge is not perfect. What is a better way?

Comment: You application generates 20000 POST requests in very quick succession, stressing the webserver to its limit, this is probably why it stops responding.  Try importing all the data in one call, not line by line.

Comment: Yes but with the one by one line solution i get the import status. So I can see that for example 1000 from 20000 lines are imported.

Comment: Is there a way to start a new ajax request after one is completed? For example put the "i++" into the completed area?

Comment: As punund said, it's much, much better to upload the CSV file itself and parse it server-side. Searching for "ajax file upload" and "php csv" should give you all the info you need. This may also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901495/what-is-the-best-way-of-showing-progress-on-an-ajax-call

Comment: I agree with other comments, you must redesign your apps. Or else you could use "async:false" in your $ajax request so the post go one by one to your server. But it's not the best way to do this.