# Run background job and display results to the user

Tags: php, csv, import, background-process

I have this php script that imports each row to my database. After it saves, in the same process it will do some more stuff, takes 1-2 sec for each row so my user prefers to send the CSV file to me, then I run in the terminal.

I want to build a page to him, so he can drop the CSV in a file input, until here ok, I saw how to make this run in background, but I really want to show in the page the results of importing, my scripts echoes the result for each row in the CSV in the terminal. **How to do something similar in the HTML?**

How to make the user drops the CSV in a file input and see the result for each row right bellow as like he had executed the script in a terminal on his screen?

**EDIT** *(making things clear)*
I want to display the script messages while it's running, I mean, for each row of the csv file, my script will output/echo the result of the import, I want to immediately display this row result to the user in the HTML page. Not after the script execution finishes. Something like a stream.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to look at using [jQuery and AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) which will achieve what you're aiming for. This allows you to send data to a script, such as PHP, and the script processes in the background before sending the response.

Comment: Ok, but, AJAX will make the request to start a background process and then die. I want to display to the user the outputs of the process. I'm thinking about logging the results to a file or queue and use long-polling ajax strategy to fetch these logs. Is this the best way? Also maybe will join an adventure thought NodeJS and SocketIO that will be basically the same ideia, logging/fetching but using proper technology (websockets) instead of long-polling. Maybe Redis to store the results.

Comment: The process can send output back to the code that made the AJAX call, there's no need to store it anywhere.

Comment: My script does output messages, while its running. Can AJAX call read them? My `onSuccess` or `done()` callback won't be fired only when the script execution finishes and returns a response?

Comment: The answer to that can be viewed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901495/what-is-the-best-way-of-showing-progress-on-an-ajax-call. Not a PHP example, but gives you the general gist.